# My javascript isn't executing

Tags: javascript, html

[edited] I am going through this Web Design Blueprints book, however the Javascript part of the code just doesnt seem to execute.. DevTools on chrome is saying:

**index.html:332 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of undefined
    at index.html:332**

i have edited the previous errors pointed out, thank you.

```
<html>
<header>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

</header> 

<body>
<style>
.blue {
color: #85C4ED;
}
.green {
color:green;
}
.white {
color:white;
}
.yellow {
color:yellow;
}
.grey-1 {
color:#222222;
}
.grey-2 {
color:#666;
}
.silver {
color:silver;
}
.left {
float:left;
}
.right {
float:right;
}
.black {
background-color: #000000;
}
.color-0 { 
background-color: #85C4ED;
}
.color-1 { 
background-color: #58ADE3;
}
.color-2 { 
background-color: #3499DB;
}
.color-3 { 
background-color: #0F85D1;
}
.color-4 { 
background-color: #0665A2;
}
.wet-asphalt {
background-color:#34495e;
}

#sky{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#sun{
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    font-size:5px;
}
#sun > i {
    font-size:12em;
}
#sun > :first-child{
    position:relative;
left: 57px;
    font-size:13em;
}
#sun > :last-child{
    position:relative;
    left: -60px;
    top:2px;
    font-size:14em;
}
#rocket > span{
-ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
transform: rotate(315deg);
position: fixed;
left: 40%;
}
#rocket > span > i:first-child{
position: fixed;
bottom: 3%;
left: 40%;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #666;
}
#rocket > span > i:nth-child(2) {
position: fixed;
bottom: 3.2%;
left: 39.8%;
background-color: #333;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 
–1px 1px 3px;
}
.fa-fire {
position: fixed;
bottom: 12px;
left: 12px;
text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
10px -10px 30px #feec85,
-20px -20px 40px #ffae34,
20px -30px 35px #ec760c,
-20px -40px 40px #cd4606,
0 -50px 65px #973716,
10px -70px 70px #451b0e;
}
.fa-plane{
-ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
transform: rotate(330deg);
background-color: #999;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 
-1px 1px 3px;
}

#earth {
float:left;
font-size: 1000vw;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
.fa-globe {
position: relative;
float:left;
bottom: 423px;
right: 350%;
}
.fa-globe.land::after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
background: green;
z-index: -1;
top: 10%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
border-radius:50%;
}
#ground {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 60px solid brown;
}
#ground > div {
width: 50%;
height: 0px;
}
#ground .left I {
font-size:8vw;
}
#ground .right i {
float: left;
}
#ground > .right > :first-child {
left:-20px;
bottom: 15px;
}
#ground .right .small {
font-size: 12vw;
}
#ground .right .large {
font-size: 14vw;
}
.curve {
border-top-right-radius: 90% 40%;
}
.curve2 {
border-top-right-radius: 80% 10%;
}
</style>


<main class="black">
<!--000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-->
<section id="space">
    <div id="p0" class="row">
    <i class="yellow fas fa-moon fa-7x"></i> 
    </i>
    </div>
    <div id="p1" class="row">
    <div id="stars">
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star yellow"></i>

    </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111-->
<section id="stratosphere" class="wet-asphalt curve2">  
    <div id="p2" class="row wet-asphalt curve"></div>
    <div id="p3" class="row color-4 curve"></div>
    <div id="p4" class="row color-3"></div>
    <div id="p5" class="row color-2"></div>
    <div id="p6" class="row color-1"></div>
</section>
<!--22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222-->
<section id="sky" class="color-1">  
    <div id="p7" class="row color-0">
            <div class="clouds">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="p8" class="row color-0">
            <div class="clouds">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-6x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-1x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="p9" class="row color-0">
            <div class="clouds">
                <i class="fa fa-plane fa-5x silver"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
    <div id="p10" class="row color-0">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-6x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-2x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-1x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-3x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-4x white"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x white"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="p11" class="row color-0"></div>
    <div id="p12" class="row color-0"></div>
    <div id="p13" class="row color-0"></div>
</section>
<!--33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333-->
<section id="objects">
      <div id="sun">
                <i class="far fa-smile green"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-circle yellow"></i>
                <i class="far fa-sun yellow"></i>
      </div>
      <div id="earth">
            <i class="fa fa-globe blue land air"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="rocket">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-rocket fa-5x grey-2"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-rocket fa-5x silver"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-fire yellow"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
</section>
<!--444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444-->
<section id="terra">
    <div id="ground">
            <div class="left green">
                <i class="fa fa-tree"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-tree"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-tree"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-tree"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-tree"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <i class="fa fa-truck silver"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-building small grey-1"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-building small grey-2"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-building large grey-2"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-industry large grey-1"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
</main>

<script ="text/javascript">



document.window.onload = function() {
        for ( i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("row").length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("row")[i].style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
        }
}  

function spreadObjects(x, vm, hm, va, ha, p, e){
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            x[i].style.position = p;
            x[i].style.top = Math.floor((Math.random()*vm)+va)+e;
            x[i].style.left = Math.floor((Math.random()*hm)+ha)+e;
        }
}
spreadObjects(document.getElementById("stars").getElementsByTagName("i"), 150, 100, 1, 1, "fixed", "%");

spreadObjects(document.getElementById("ground").getElementsByClassName("fa-tree"), 0, 14, -(window.innerHeight/28), 1, "relative", "px");

spreadObjects(document.getElementById("ground").getElementsByClassName("right")[0].getElementsByClassName("small"), 0, 14,-(window.innerHeight/13), 1, "relative", "px");

spreadObjects(document.getElementById("ground").getElementsByClassName("right")[0].getElementsByClassName("large"), 0, 14,-(window.innerHeight/15), 1, "relative", "px");

for 
(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("clouds").length; i++)
{
spreadObjects(document.getElementsByClassName("clouds")[i].getElementsByTagName("i"), window.innerHeight*.75, window.innerWidth*.75, 1, 1-(window.innerWidth/2), "relative", "px");
}



</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: open the developer console (F12 on most browsers) and check if an error occured. You also seem to have problems with case sensitivity where you have `i` and `I` (they are not the same!!)

Comment: please add your full code and show if any errors in the console

Comment: also in your loops variable is declared as uppercase and incremental in lowercase

Comment: you don't seem to load the code at all... do you have script tag in your index.html?

Comment: replace document.getElementById("body") with window.onload

Comment: ah so it says:index.html:391 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null
    at index.html:391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your website *'agwebdesign.net'*, it seems there is no element with Id *'body'* in your HTML file. Thus giving an error.

Also you would want to check the case sensitivity for the loop variables, which otherwise may end up creating infinite loops making your website to not respond

Comment: I've changed that however the error in chrome devtools is saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of undefined"

Comment: I might have to take a look at your updated index.html.

Comment: document.window.onload = function() {

Please change the above line to :

window.onload = function() {

Comment: If you change the above line to 

`window.onload = function() {`

This will do the trick for you.

Comment: oh my god, ive been staring at that for hours.. that finally worked. i wonder why it says in the book to wite "document..." thanks so much